# Column '' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate

This table is for the purpose of demo, but I have physical table whose values I need to insert into another table. there is no primary key in this table. The question I have is - Is the only way to get all the data in one SELECT statement using aggregate values (using SUM, AVG, etc.) and non-aggregate fields is listing all the not aggregate fields in the GROUP BY clause or is there some other way as well?  What would be the impact of listing a large number of fields in the GROUP BY clause?
Here is the sample:

```
    CREATE TABLE #SummaryData(
       [Col_Name] varchar(20) not NULL,
       [Col_Date] datetime NULL,
       [ColC] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
       [ColD] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
       [ColE] [decimal](18, 4) NULL
       )

       INSERT INTO #SummaryData ([Col_Name],[Col_Date],[ColC],[ColD],[ColE])
       VALUES ('BOA'      ,'03/10/2017',     2.4507 ,33536.0000   ,0.0073)

       INSERT INTO #SummaryData ([Col_Name],[Col_Date],[ColC],[ColD],[ColE])
       VALUES ('BOA'      , '03/11/2017'    , 9.9419,47041.0000, 0.0088)

       INSERT INTO #SummaryData ([Col_Name],[Col_Date],[ColC],[ColD],[ColE])
       VALUES ('Merrill Lynch',    '03/10/2017',     2.8152,       32371.0000,   0.0042)
       INSERT INTO #SummaryData ([Col_Name],[Col_Date],[ColC],[ColD],[ColE])
       VALUES ('Merrill Lynch',    '03/11/2017',     9.9333,       35671.0000,   0.0444)

--NOTE: Next SELECT will be used to INSERT data into another table, so I need all fields

       SELECT [Col_Name],[Col_Date],[ColC],
       CASE WHEN SUM([ColE]) > 0 THEN SUM([ColD])/SUM([ColE]) ELSE 0 END AS SomeVal , [ColE]
       FROM #SummaryData
       GROUP BY [Col_Name],[Col_Date],[ColE],[ColC]
```

If I do not include ColE and ColC in the GROUP BY clause I get:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Column '#SummaryData.Col_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: That's correct.  Unless *every* instance of a field in the field selection is in an aggregate function, that field must be in the GROUP BY clause.  Since your SELECT is returning both `ColC` and `ColE`, you need to include them in the GROUP BY.  It's difficult to tell what results you even want, however, because your example doesn't appear to require aggregation at all.  I suggest you post your expected results.

Comment: Either remove cole and colc from your select, or add them to the group by.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use an aggregate function, all non-aggregate values in your SELECT statement need to appear in your group by statement. If you want to insert aggregate values then you need to use the group by. With that said, why do you need to use the SUM function? This would only be needed if you had duplicate entries you were consolidating. The below query avoids the SUM and thus does not need a group by.

```
SELECT [Col_Name],[Col_Date],[ColC],
CASE WHEN [ColE] > 0 THEN [ColD]/[ColE] ELSE 0 END AS SomeVal , [ColE]
FROM @SummaryData
```

Comment: Actually, this is just a sample, but I have a long query in which I have to use a number of aggregate and non-aggregate fields. #1. By using SUM the values are getting Rounded. #2. is it okay to group by all the remaining non-aggregate fields? OR, shall I just insert the non-aggregate fields first and then update the table with aggregate fields?

Comment: Grouping by the non-aggregate fields is fine. Group by has a performance hit, but is required for aggregates and prevents duplicate records when aggregating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all of the records, you can't use a GROUP BY at all.  If you need intermediate values such as SUM(ColE) and SUM(ColD) from the whole table, you can calculate them and [put them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql) into a [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql).  Then you can use the variables however you want to.

```
DECLARE @SumE DECIMAL(18, 4);
SELECT @SumE = SUM(ColE) FROM #SummaryData
```

Answer (score 0):

That's totally correct, `Group by` has all non aggregate functions.

but Why ?

***Simple Demo:-***

```
create table emp (empid int , departmentName varchar(15))
go
insert into emp values (1 , 'HR')
insert into emp values (2 , 'HR')
insert into emp values (3 , 'HR')
insert into emp values (4 , 'Sales')
insert into emp values (5 , 'Sales')
insert into emp values (7 , 'Developemnet')
insert into emp values (8 , 'Developemnet')
insert into emp values (9 , 'Developemnet')
insert into emp values (10 , 'Developemnet')
insert into emp values (11 , 'Developemnet')
```

***The Desired Result is:-***

```
countEmpID  departmentName
5            Developemnet
3               HR
2               Sales
```

so for achieving that, you **MUST** select count (empid) & departmentName then Group by with non aggregate functions (departmentName) because this is way to making groups via next code:-

```
select count (empid) countEmpID, departmentName
from emp
group by departmentName
```

and this way if you didn't put non aggragate functions in group by, the next error will be raised:-

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 Column 'emp.departmentName' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Hope it helps.